# 2006 Scion XB sometimes unlocks doors, sometimes doesn't

Tags: toyota, locks, door, scion, unlock

My 2006 Scion XB has some problems with unlocking the doors. Sometimes when I press the unlock button it doesn't unlock the driver and passenger door. So when I try to do it manually by pulling up the lock it is jammed and doesn't not come up. After about 5 minutes if manually unlock it and it it finally unlocks. Does anyone know why?

Comment: A few questions: So is it partially unlocking, then completing the unlock on it's own 5 minutes later? Or do you have to try again? What happens with subsequent unlock attempts?

Comment: I try unlocking it, and then it doesn't unlock so I wait 5 minutes and then I manually have to unlock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the second post about your car. You should state all the problems in one post for a better answer.

Check the connections in the driver side panel for the window and the lock/unlock switches. Then trace back to the fuse box and look for loose connections or loose fuses.